# Selecting a new close reason from the site-specific list is not being recognized in Reopen review?

Tags: support, review

I was trying to [review](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/196022) a post in the Reopen queue.  I felt that the edits made had changed it from being "needs details" to off-topic for a site-specific reason ("real-world science question").

After selecting the appropriate response from the submenu, the system would not accept the submission, claiming no response was selected.  (A pink error message appeared at the top of the page.)  I cancelled the "Leave closed" action and started it again, and got the same result.

Unfortunately I'm afraid my review was invalidated by a mod before I was able to screencap the behaviour, so I don't have any evidence. :(

Comment: I am moderately annoyed that the "Similar questions" list did not present me with this duplicate before I posted my question.  In fact, if I try again, the Similar questions list does not even present me with _this_ question.

Comment: That, unfortunately, is one of the known problems of the SE search functionality.